# How to use GetComponent for inactive object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use `GetComponent` for inactive gameObject which is called "Character":

```
 testingCollison test;
    void Start()
    {
      
        GameObject inter = GameObject.Find("Character");
        test = inter.GetComponent<testingCollison>();
}
```

but it is giving this error:

[image]

it is pointing to this line : `test = inter.GetComponent<testingCollison>();`

I tried replacing `GetComponect` with `GetComponentInChildren` as I found it as a solution when I looked up this issue, but it didn't make any difference.

How can I use getComponent of inactive object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetComponent works on inactive GameObjects.

The GameObject.Find however can only return active GameObjects. Inactive GameObjects cannot be found.

Possible solutions:

- Enable the GameObject (so it can found) but disable its components.
- Pass the GameObject as reference from the editor inspector.
- Save the GameObject reference in some intermediate active GameObject, and acquire through script.

Comment: Great. Thank you so much, the second option worked for me.